# Integrating a GWTP project with a standard GWT project

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwt-gin, gwt-mvp, gwtp

I have a GWTP application which has no entry point because I don't ever need to run this application on its own. Rather I want to use it within a standard GWT application which has an entry point, implements its own history management mechanism, uses its own implementation of MVP framework, has its own dependency injection and so on.

The question is: Is it even possible to nicely integrate a GWTP application within a standard GWT application?

Consider this use-case for example: I want to show a popup dialog when a button is clicked in a view that is implemented in the GWT application. The popup dialog is a GWTP PresenterWidget implemented in the GWTP application. How is it possible for a non GWTP presenter to show a popup and make sure all life cycle events are properly called.

I know it's a broad question but I'm looking to see if any body has ever tried to integrate two such applications together. If not is there any advice on how to approach this problem at all.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that kind of context, I would suggest to build your home made mvp framework. It would be easier and cleaner than using a subset of the capabilities of GWTP.

That being said, it's not imposible, but you will have to use a complete hierarchy of presenter / presenter widgets. But that won't mean that the lifecycle will work... The lifecycle of GWTP is strongly tied to internal Navigation Events and if your application doesn't use this feature of GWTP, you're likely to lose all its advantages.

Here's how you can embed a GWTP application in your own already existing application:
https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Website-Embedding

We've already worked on migrating an existing application to GWTP by embedding the existing application IN GWTP while gradually migrating the existing code base, but not the other way around.